# Can you find a trophy on this page?

Tags: visual

> [image][image]
>   [image][image]

There's a trophy on this page. Can you find it?

Comment: Note that the blue ball machine is only half the fun without the sound: https://www.csee.umbc.edu/~squire/blueball.htm

Answer (score 37, accepted):

It's here:

> [image: Puzzling.SE screenshot with freehand circle around the Achievements inbox icon in the top bar, which looks like a trophy]

Of course, this answer is only valid

> if you're using the desktop version of the site. On the mobile version and in the Stack Exchange app, there's no such trophy, as @StephenS notes.

Comment: Pure evil!. Great find

Comment: LOL. Next is what? :D

Comment: My bad for disqualifying mobile web users. I'm a frequent mobile user, too.

Comment: I'm really glad I didn't spend a ton of time looking for it, since I'm on the app.

Answer (score 19):

Another answer:

> In medical practice, hormonal and nerve inputs that maintain an organ or body part are said to have trophic effects. A diminished muscular trophic condition is designated as **atrophy**. Atrophy is reduction in size of cell, organ or tissue, after attaining its normal mature growth.
>
> You have 4 repeated cells instead of one healthy one!
>
>  Source : [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atrophy)

Comment: Smart. Haven't thought about it that way.

Answer (score 1):

I found a trophy on the page.

> [image: Picture of this question, with the word trophy under the question's picture highlighted in yellow.]
>
>  Similar logic to the original. I hope it's not "cheating". I was thinking of uploading an answer with a picture of a trophy but felt it maybe pushes the limits a little bit.

Comment: In similar fashion, lbh pbhyq unir zragvbarq gur jbeq 'gebcul' va gur dhrfgvba gvgyr ([ROT13](https://rot13.com/)).

Comment: I had thought of explicitly stating that the English word "trophy" does not count, so my bad for not declaring it.